# Installing Mediaelch on 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04, repository

I like using Mediaelch.  When I replaced my Ubuntu 14.04 with a fresh 15.04 installation, apt-get kept giving me not-found errors when looking for Mediaelch's packages.

I followed the instructions at [Mediaelch](http://www.kvibes.de/en/mediaelch/download/), and its overview at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~kvibes/+archive/ubuntu/mediaelch).  No joy either way.

I'm guessing the repository hasn't been updated yet for 15.04.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install Mediaelch in Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid) using the source for 14.04.

**Method: 1** Adding Repository and Signing Key

Turns out adding a repo and its key manually is no big deal.  Create a file, add the info from Launchpad, add the key, update and install:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kvibes/mediaelch/ubuntu trusty main\n deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kvibes/mediaelch/ubuntu trusty main\n" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kvibes-mediaelch-ubuntu-trusty.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 00DAEE81 && echo That worked. || echo That totally failed.
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mediaelch
```

Not so hard afterall.

**Method: 2** Add New Repo and Edit for Older Source

Don't know anything about manually adding repos and signing keys, so I just added the repository according to instructions and merely replaced "vivid" with "trusty" in its list file.  I didn't bother renaming the .list file.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kvibes/mediaelch
sudo sh -c 'sed -i "s/vivid/trusty/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kvibes-ubuntu-mediaelch-vivid.list'
```

Then just update and install

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mediaelch
```

Worked a charm.